# Fire function when input is generated with an id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a normal ng-repeat with its model. Everything is working fine except for my inputs... I need to run a JavaScript function the moment the input gets its data.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="game-time-passed-{{$index}}" class="form-control" 
   readonly="true" value="{{games.gameStartTime}}">
</div>
```

I just have no access to the input the moment it is generated. I know that I can't use onload on inputs... I could go for it when everything is done, but that doesn't feel right. I need to alter the data the moment it enters the input box and register a kind of a timer on that input box with its value.

I also could place a script tag under my input and start a self invoked function, but I want to keep things clean. Preferably a angular attribute oder something else like:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="game-time-passed-{{$index}}" class="form-control"
   readonly="true" input-loaded="myFunction(this)">
</div>
```

**In short: Is there anyway to access inputs when they are loaded or fire some kind of an event whith their value? Plain JavaScript would be very nice.**

Comment: Seems like you are approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes thanks for your answer, but I said plain JavaScript. Look my answer to see my complete solution.

Comment: @epascarello please explain what you mean by 'wrong way'. Take a look at my anser and tell me if my solution is better or if there is room for  improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys I've found an answer myself after some struggles.

I'm using a custom directive which is fired when the last element of ng-repeat is reached and is rendered, still not seen in browser. Just what I wanted to do.

Here is my solution:

**1. Register a custom directive through a namespace from another function:**

```
const CUSTOMDIRECTIVE = require('./CustomDirectives.js');

// Main APP:
angular.module('LoLWatcher', []);

/**
* Register Directives
*/

// Register Sepctate Timers Directive
angular.module('LoLWatcher').directive('spectateFinishedLoadingTimers', CUSTOMDIRECTIVE.spectateFinishedLoadingTimers);
```

**2. In my custom directives my code looks like this now:**

```
var CUSTOMDIRECTIVES = module.exports = CUSTOMDIRECTIVES || {};

/**
* Global Variables and Modules
*/
// Error Logger
const ERRORLOGGER = require('../Helpers/ErrorLogger.js');


CUSTOMDIRECTIVES.spectateFinishedLoadingTimers = function(){
  // Activate Strict Mode
  'use strict';
  // Add Name Parameter to Function
  CUSTOMDIRECTIVES.spectateFinishedLoadingTimers.FuncName = 'CUSTOMDIRECTIVES.spectateFinishedLoadingTimers';

  try {
    // Return directive Object.
    return {
      // Restrict by Attribute.
      restrict: 'A',
      // Link Function to directive.
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        // If is last element in ng-repeat...
        if (scope.$last) {
          // ... run async callback from attribute.
           scope.$evalAsync(attr.spectateFinishedLoadingTimers);
        }
      }
    };

  } catch (e) {
    //Logg complete error
    console.log(e);
    //future user error codes
    console.log(ERRORLOGGER.standardErrorLog(CUSTOMDIRECTIVES.spectateFinishedLoadingTimers.FuncName, 'functionError'));
  }
};
```

**3. After that I had to modify my html with my custom attribute to this ($last &&... makes sure to fire my function only if the last element was reached):**

```
<div class="row-fluid"  ng-model="personList" ng-repeat="person in personList| filter:featuredPersons(filter)" spectate-finished-loading-timers="$last && timersFinishedLoading()">
```

**4. The last thing to do was to register my custom function to my controller/scope:**

```
// Function fired from Attribute
$scope.timersFinishedLoading = function(){
  console.log('done rendering but not loaded in browser');
  // Plain easy JS!
  let div = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=time-passed-]');
  for(let i= 0; i < div.length; i++){
    /**
     * Do Stuff with Timers
     */
  }
};
```

This all allows me to get my values from all generated inputs and alter them befor they appear in the browser, or in my case in electron. Since I work alot with namespaces and modules this saved me the 'dirty' part.

One last thing, if you guys downvote a question, at least write a comment why you did it and help others to improve! We all startet small and are still learning... just saying.

I hope this will help someone with the same problem.

Regards,
Megajin

Answer (score 1):

The point of Angular and similar frameworks is that you don't have to deal with the DOM and only worry about the data. Your input appears to have bindings to data. In this case, use [`observe`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) on the keypath to run a function when that data changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found a solution with custom directives. Anyway I'm gonna take a look at 'observe'.